# SharePoint Token type is not allowed

Tags: windows, azure, authentication, go, sharepoint

I am trying to authenticate into SharePoint using Gosip package (https://github.com/koltyakov/gosip). I am using an authentication object but each time I try I get an '{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Token type is not allowed."}'

```
auth := &strategy.AuthCnfg{
    SiteURL:      os.Getenv("SPAUTH_SITEURL"),
    ClientID:     os.Getenv("SPAUTH_CLIENTID"),
    ClientSecret: os.Getenv("SPAUTH_CLIENTSECRET"),
}
```

I have registered the new app using https://{site}/_layouts/15/AppRegNew.aspx and given full permission to the app using https://{site}/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx

```
 <AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
   <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection" 
   Right="FullControl" />
 </AppPermissionRequests>
```

I can likewise see the app is available in Site App Permission list using https://{site}/_layouts/15/appprincipals.aspx but I keep getting the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[similar issue](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/284402/sharepoint-online-authorization-issue-token-type-is-not-allowed) have happened before, you can try to see if this helps your situation.